# Using Java Generics to Return Wrapped Objects

Tags: java, generics

I'm trying to write a generic solution to a filtering problem where we have several lists that will be constrained by a list of filters (or constraints).

Supporting this, I have the following generic class:

```
public class Constrained<T> {
    private T object;

    List<TraitFilter> filters;

    public T getObject() {
        return object;
    }
}
```

This would allow me to have an object of any class wrapped by a list of constraints.

Now I'm trying to write a service that can run the filters. I'd want to be able to write the function in the service like this:

```
List<T> filtered(Constrained<T>, traits);
```

But Java does not like this. It says that T is not defined. I swapped to the following:

```
List<? extends Object> filtered(List<Constrained<?>> possible, Traits traits);
```

Java like this, both in the Interface in which the function was defined and the implementation, until I was writing a test that actually tried to use the function.

```
final List<Constrained<DecisionTemplate>> dtList =
   Arrays.asList(ConstrainedDecisionTemplateFixtures.LUO_ONLY_POLICIES(),
                 ConstrainedDecisionTemplateFixtures.LUOA_AGREEMENT());

List<DecisionTemplate> actual = instance.filtered(dtList, expectedTraits);
```

My IDE is reporting the following error message:

```
 Wrong 1st argument type. Found
 'java.util.List<Constrained<DecisionTemplate>>', required:
 'java.util.List<Constrained<? extends java.lang.Object>>
```

What do I need to change to be able to use a generic function that returns the unwrapped object of class T?

Comment: *It says that T is not defined.* - well you have not introduced it. Use `<T> List<T> filtered(Constrained<T>, traits);`

Comment: `List<T> filtered(Constrained<T>, traits);` does not compile for multiple reasons. Where did you try to place that method? `<T> List<T> filtered(Constrained<T> c, Traits t);` would be probably be fine.

Comment: Tim, your suggestion is exactly what I needed to do! Please make this an answer so I can up-vote it. :)

Answer (score 0):

In order for you to be able to declare:

```
List<T> filtered(List<Constrained<T>> traits);
```

(note that I'm assuming your desired parameter is actually a `List` of `Constrained`, not a single one)...

You need the interface where the method is declared to be generic, and parametrized with `T`.

You will want to narrow the implementation down to a specific parametrized type, i.e. `DecisionTemplate` in the implementation.

You can also declare a generic method, with the following syntax:

```
<T extends DecisionTemplate>List<T> filtered(List<Constrained<T>> traits);
```

... if you don't want to have a generic interface.

**Example**

```
// with a generic method...
interface Foo {
    <T extends DecisionTemplate>List<T> filtered(List<Constrained<T>> traits);
}
class Blah implements Foo {
    @Override
    public <T extends DecisionTemplate> List<T> filtered(
        List<Constrained<T>> traits) {
        // TODO populate
        return null;
    }
}

// with a generic class/interface
interface FooGeneric<T> {
    List<T> filtered(List<Constrained<T>> traits);
}
class BlahGeneric implements FooGeneric<DecisionTemplate> {
    @Override
    public List<DecisionTemplate> filtered(
        List<Constrained<DecisionTemplate>> traits) {
        // TODO populate
        return null;
    }
}
```

**Clients**

```
// invoking generic method

// TODO populate
List<Constrained<DecisionTemplate>> list = new ArrayList<>(); 
List<DecisionTemplate> filtered = new Blah().filtered(list);

// invoking generic class/interface's method

// TODO populate
List<Constrained<DecisionTemplate>> anotherList = new ArrayList<>();
List<DecisionTemplate> anotherFiltered = new BlahGeneric().filtered(anotherList);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Mena. What I'm trying to do, though, is keep from having to define the filtering for every class I want to be constrained.